# Is EXECUTE AS OWNER in msdb a security risk?

Tags: sql-server, security, best-practices

I've been tasked with creating a system that allows non-privileged users to start and stop SQL Server Agent jobs.  I'm creating stored procedures in the `dbo` schema in the `msdb` database using the `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` construct to run `EXEC dbo.sp_start_job <JobID>;`, etc.

The [Books Online topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx#Anchor_2) about `EXECUTE AS` says this is a "[best practice](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickmalik/2013/01/28/rumination-on-the-concept-of-best-practice/)":

> Specify a login or user that has the least privileges required to perform the operations defined in the module. For example, do not specify a database owner account unless those permissions are required.

In my case, `EXECUTE AS OWNER` indicates `[sa]`, since those modules are in the `dbo` schema, in the msdb database, which is always owned by `[sa]`.

Am I inadvertently creating a security risk by doing this?

I'm not passing in any parameters that could be used in a SQL injection attack since the only parameter *ever* being passed in is a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` representing the job affected.

The user running the stored procedures that have `EXECUTE AS OWNER` have no access to the msdb database aside from membership in a database role I've explicitly created which `GRANTs` them the `EXECUTE` permission on the stored procs.

One of the conditions of this project is the users in question should *not* be able to run the SQL Server Agent GUI tools in any way.  This rules out giving them membership in the built-in `SQLAgentUserRole` role.  I'd also rather not modify the permissions on `dbo.sp_start_job`, etc, since I'm trying to not modify anything that SQL Server itself depends on (other than obviously adding items to the msdb database itself).

The code in question is [here](http://www.sqlserver.science/tools/allowing-users-to-start-and-stop-sql-server-agent-jobs/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In and of itself, no, you are probably not adding a security risk.  As long as no one but a sysadmin can alter the procedure and as long as the ONLY thing the procedure can do is start a job I don't see a problem.

The risks come in with the fact that MSDB is (and is supposed to be) marked as `TRUSTWORTHY`.  That means that by using `EXECUTE AS OWNER` you are able to impersonate the SERVER level permissions.  In this case since it's `sa` that means you could create a procedure to grant another user sysadmin.

That does mean you do want to limit permissions to MSDB though.

Comment: That's what I thought... I've just been reading your [post](https://sqlstudies.com/2014/02/26/impersonating-a-server-level-permissions/) - interesting read!